# Does mercurial support having an alias for the default branch?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way in mercurial to give an alternate name to the default branch while still having `default` work as before?  I.e., Can I set things up so that either `hg update main` or `hg update default` will bring me to the default branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hand a bookmark named 'main' on the default branch like:

```
hg bookmark --rev default main
```

That bookmark will start out on the "most tipward" changeset on the default branch.  And the bookmark will follow that along when you commit (including committing merges).

In general though try to keep using the name 'default' for your active development work.

Comment: Thanks.  Why do you suggest sticking to default?

Comment: two problems detected: 1. Command is `hg bookmark`, 2. for --rev option help states: "If -r/--rev is given, the new bookmark will not be made active even if -i/--inactive is not given."

Comment: Thanks @LazyBadger.  I dropped the 's'.  It will be made active as soon as he `hg update`s to it, which is his plan.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg This explains the "why" of the recommendation: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching#Don.27t_use_a_name_other_than_default_for_your_main_development_branch It's not an absolute, but in general it's a good idea.

Comment: @Ry4an, from your link, "If you try to use some other name for your "main" branch, users will get a more or less random branch when they clone and commit things in the wrong place" ... I think that sounds like a caveat against something different, like doing primary development on a different named branch.  Are you sure that creating that bookmark could change what happens when somebody updates or commits without specifying a branch?  Apologies if I'm misunderstanding that FAQ warning.

Comment: nope, the bookmark is safe so long as you keep it tracking default.  It's just that if you fill your docs with instructions to update to 'main' people will get confused if they diverge.  Why not just use 'default' altogether?

Comment: @Ry4an: I don't think it's easy to maintain a `main` bookmark like this. It will be left behind sooner or later. So I agree with your suggestion to just stick with `default`. There has been a [recent thread](http://mercurial.markmail.org/thread/vgsa7pbv2osnovtj) about bookmarks and named branches. See also [this thread](http://mercurial.markmail.org/thread/l4vngxbjblglhemw).